# Change my first, I'm entertaining

Tags: riddle

> Change my first, I'm entertaining
>
> Change my first, I can kill
>
> Change my middle, I'll be over
>
> Change my middle, I'm some bloke
>
> Change my last, I'm made of skin
>
> Change my last, I'm better than gin

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hmm, I could identify 4.5 out of 6...

Who am I?:

> **run**

Change my first, I'm entertaining:

> **fun**

Change my first, I can kill:

> **gun**

Change my middle, I'll be over:

> **ran** (Thanks for oAlt's comment)

Change my middle, I'm some bloke:

> **Ron** (A male member in Korean K-pop group) (Thanks for El-Guest’s comment, better explanation)

Change my last, I'm made of skin:

> **rug**

Change my last, I'm better than gin:

> **rum**

Comment: Maybe rot13(eha orpbzrf ena, juvpu vf abj va cnfg grafr, naq eha orpbzrf Eba, juvpu zvtug or n ovg sne-srgpurq, ohg fgvyy vg'f n inyvq anzr sbe n oybxr)

Comment: Ron is also just a male name, fitting the clues for “some bloke”.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, all your guesses are right! Good job!

Comment: @PaperTowel Thanks! I can't wait for your next riddle who-am-I puzzle :P